# How to show asymptotic normality assuming the null hypothesis is true?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let's assume a test statistics having "asymptotic normality", the $N(0,1)$ becomes my test distribution.

I also have a hypothesis where $H_0$ is: $P=\text{parameter (from MLE)} = P_0$ true parameter from $H_0$.

$$\frac{P - P_0}{\sqrt{P(1-P)/n}}$$

(the variance under the division is derived from Fisher expected info)

I struggle to see what the term **"under $H_0$"** have to say for the normality part, except I get two parameters are very close in distance.

What **"tools"** may I use to show my test statistics conforms to asymptotic normality (important->) **assuming null hypothesis is 
true**.

Thank you!

Comment: Please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with formatting.

Comment: Thank you, so it does support Latex ... good to know!

Comment: CLT convergence in distribution de-Movire Laplace